# ObserveOn doesn't work

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I start learn `Rx` for Android and I get one error. This is my code:

In my `Subscriber` I print to log current thread name:

```
Subscriber<Integer> integerSubscriber = new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        // ... onCompleted, onError
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer s) {
            Log.e("RX", "threadName " + getCurrThreadName());
        }
};
```

Here I want to run code in background and get data from Observable in mainThread:

```
 ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
 list.add(...) // creating data list

 Observable.from(list)
     .map(TransformFunc.getTransformer())
     .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .observeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
     .subscribe(integerSubscriber);

...
```

Other code:
    static String getCurrThreadName() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

```
static class TransformFunc implements Func1<String, Integer> {

    private static TransformFunc instance;

    static TransformFunc getTransformer() {
       ... // return instance

        @Override
        public Integer call(@NonNull String s) {
            ...
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                Log.e("RX", "threadName " + getCurrThreadName());
            ...

            return s.length();
        }
}
```

But when I run this code on device I see white screen 5-10 sec and this in logs:

```
12-02 16:34:39.374 26086-26086/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName main
12-02 16:34:39.378 26086-26180/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName pool-1-thread-2
12-02 16:34:43.375 26086-26086/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName main
12-02 16:34:43.379 26086-26216/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName pool-1-thread-3
12-02 16:34:47.376 26086-26086/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName main
12-02 16:34:47.396 26086-26253/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName pool-1-thread-4
12-02 16:34:51.376 26086-26086/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName main
12-02 16:34:51.398 26086-26292/com.shevart.fitnessnotes E/RX: threadName pool-1-thread-5
```

Why `onNext()` called before `call()` in **map**?

Comment: You should add more information to your logging to know which log matches which method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to observe on main thread, not the other way arround.

```
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `.subscribeOn()` you're basically telling that `Observable` to do its work on a particular `Scheduler`. By `.observeOn()` on the other hand you are telling `Observable` to send you all notifications on that thread.

So you need to swap your subscription and observing schedulers.

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```